# Files built using pyinstaller --onefile no longer deletes their temporary _MEI directories after the february 24th windows update

Tags: windows, powershell, pyinstaller

We have several minor python scripts in our test environment, and to avoid having to install python on all machines running them, i built them all to single exe files using pyinstaller with the --onefile/-F flag. This have been working perfectly fine for over a year now.

Recently however, i noticed the Temp folders filling up at an extremely rapid pace on all computers running the environment. I eventually discovered that a huge amount of _MEIXXXXXX folders in the Temp directory were the source.

At first, i thought that i had made some sort of error when using pyinstaller, or that they had built up over a long time since we started using it, but i eventually realised that this had started at exactly february 24th 10:00 CET on every single computer, and that it weren't just the new scripts not deleting their temp-folders but also scripts which haven't been built for over 6 months.

There also didn't seem to be any difference whether the scripts were closed by hand (i.e. clicking X) or closed via powershell (terminating the process), as both the test-servers and people running them manually were affected simultaneously.

This makes me think that it must have had something to do with the new windows update installed at that time. As a temporary fix, I've been using powershell-scripts to regularly clear the folders, but it really doesn't feel like a good long term solution, and i'm therefore wondering if anyone else have been affected, and if there's a way to solve it?

Comment: Try to use `--runtime-tmpdir PATH` flag in pyinstaller to change  tmp directory may be this fix you problem.

Comment: @Vad Whilst it doesn't seem to solve the underlying problem of temporary files remaining, i guess it'll at least make them easier to keep track of. Thanks.

Comment: It's finally fixed in the 5.3 release. Just update pyinstaller.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was there from a very long time but they recently fixed it in the 5.3 release. So just update Pyinstaller and rebuilt your one-file application.

Now the _MEI folder gets deleted if we close the parent window or even if we end the process in task manager.

See the full changelog [here](https://pyinstaller.org/en/v5.3/CHANGES.html#id1)